# More than 24 hours: We couldn't parse the input provided as a Time value

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a column with time data in text format with more than 24 hours that I need to convert into a time format. However, times > 24 hours result in errors: "We couldn't parse the input provided as a Time value."

Sample Data:

| Time |
| --- |
| 00:00:00 |
| 00:00:01 |
| 00:01:00 |
| 01:00:00 |
| 24:00:00 |
| 168:00:00 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In powerquery, if data is in column **Time**, add column .. custom column ... with formula

```
= #duration(0,Number.From(Text.Split([Time],":"){0}), Number.From(Text.Split([Time],":"){1}),Number.From( Text.Split([Time],":"){2}))
```

then transform the type to duration

[image]

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each #duration(0,Number.From(Text.Split([Time],":"){0}), Number.From(Text.Split([Time],":"){1}),Number.From( Text.Split([Time],":"){2})),type duration)
in  #"Added Custom1"
```

Answer (score 1):

The **Time** data type is limited to 24 hours, but the **Duration** data type can be used instead. Here's the M-Code to achieve the transformation:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromList(
        {
            "00:00:00", 
            "00:00:01", 
            "00:01:00", 
            "01:00:00", 
            "24:00:00", 
            "168:00:00"
        }, 
        null, 
        {"Duration String"}
    ),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(
        Source, "Duration", each 
        let
            AllHours = Number.FromText(Text.BeforeDelimiter([Duration String], ":")),
            Days = Number.IntegerDivide(AllHours, 24),
            Hours = Number.Mod(AllHours, 24),
            Minutes = Number.FromText(Text.BetweenDelimiters([Duration String], ":", ":")),
            Seconds = Number.FromText(Text.AfterDelimiter([Duration String], ":", 1)),
            Duration = #duration(Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds)
        in
            Duration,
        type duration
    )
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Excel formula. If you have your text durations in the range `A2:A7`, then it would be enough using the following simple formula in `B2` to convert it to a numeric value representing the days (It works under O365, I haven't tested it under older versions):

```
 1*A2:A7
```

To understand what it does is basically the following calculation on each cell:

```
=SUM(TEXTSPLIT(A2,":") * {3600,60,1})/86400
```

it converts every element to seconds, sums it, and divides it by a number of seconds in a day: `24*60*60=86400`. To visualize the result in the proper format, you just need to use the following one `d.hh:mm:ss`.

[image: excel output1]

as you can see it is able to return, `1s`, `1min`, `1h`, `1day`, `7days` converting it to the appropriate unit of time.

If you want **exactly the same format as the input entered in text format** for your numeric values in range `B2:B7`, use instead: `[hh]:mm:ss`:

[image: excel output1]

**Note**: I have entered the input data as text prefixing them with an apostrophe (`'`) and with the following format: `hh:mm:ss`. For example: `'168:00:00`.